# Formating integers of different decimal values Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, formatting

I am plotting a sequence of numbers with different decimal values. The output for the numbers is strange. For the 10,000 (5 decimal places) it sometimes prints 1e-05 but then other instances it prints 5.9999999999999995e-05. My questions are two fold, what is the reason behind showing the numbers in different formats ? and How can I efficiently format them. Below is a sample of the distribution.

```
1e-05
2e-05
3.0000000000000008e-05
4e-05
5e-05
5.9999999999999995e-05
7.000000000000001e-05
8e-05
9e-05
0.0001
0.0002
0.00030000000000000003
0.0004
0.0005
0.0006000000000000001
0.0007000000000000001
0.0008000000000000001
0.0009000000000000002
0.001
0.002
0.003
0.004
```

Comment: Looks like a rounding artefact

Comment: Please provide the code that's producing this output. Also, you say "decimal," but also "integer;" you should probably be using [`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html), which will not suffer from the kind of rounding errors you seem to be seeing here.

Comment: could you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)